# tbb::task_group: Number of threads used by application doesnot go down after tbb:task_group object is destructed

Tags: multithreading, tbb

I have created a tbb::task_group and added multiple task to it. In the end I wait() on the tasks to complete. I was profiling the code and saw that the number of threads used by my application have increased (as visible in Window's Task Manager). However when the tbb::task_group object is destructed, the thread count does not decrease.

Additionally if I call the same code block again (without restarting the application), the number of threads sometimes increases and sometimes not.

Is this an expected behavior? If yes, how can I make sure the threads created previously are reused?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is expected behavior. It is done specifically to reuse threads between parallel algorithms. You can verify it by marking threads with thread-local variables (TBB provides `combinable` class) or looking into callbacks of `task_scheduler_observer`.

TBB always but lazily create the number of threads specified at the initialization time - even if you run only single task. By default the number of TBB worker threads equals to the number of HW threads (cores*HT) minus one for the application thread.

BTW, I'd not recommend you using `tbb::task` which is for advanced cases, check out `tbb::parallel_invoke` or `tbb::task_group` first which are high-level interfaces to tasks. Or even better, look whether your algorithm can be expressed on even more higher level using things like `parallel_for`, `parallel_reduce` (possibly with custom Range), `parallel_pipeline`, `flow::graph`, etc.

Comment: But then why does it need to create more threads the following time the same piece of code is executed? Additionally the tasks are created on the go and hence i cannot use parllel_for and other similar techniques

Comment: pipeline, `parallel_do`, `task_group`, and Flow graph allow to create tasks on the go.

Comment: probably because not all the threads where created when the first task was executed. TBB always but lazily create the number of threads specified in the initialization time. Updating the answer

Comment: I am not sure if I get you but let me put my observation more statistically. Initially my application had x threads. After my code completed it had x+n threads. I ran the code again, it then had x+2n thread. In the next run, my threads did not increase and remained at x+2n. However in the next run task manager showed them as x+3n

Additionally I am sorry I was creating tbb:task_group not tbb::task. Correcting my post.

Comment: Your x makes no sense unless you put it in relation to P which is number of hardware threads. And if you initialized TBB with specefic number of threads it should also be mentioned

Comment: To be precise, they increased by 7 as my hardware concurency is 8. Additionally i didnot do any initialization. Also I found out that this behaviour doesnot happen all the time

Comment: So, say it again connecting all the numbers together. I still don't understand whether do you see number of threads more than 8. And what is your concern here.

Comment: So basically when i create a tbb::task_group object and add call run on it, i see the number of threads in my application increase by 7. Now i call the same routine again which creates another tbb::task_group object and adds tasks to it. I see the number of threads have again increased by 7. Ideally this should not have happened. The threads created by previous instance of tbb::task_thread should have been reused for the latest instance

Comment: and they are. Are you sure that your HW thread count isn't 16? It is not only the number of cores but it doubles when Hyper Threading is enabled.